# Reciprocal Frame Design in Sverchok

Tags: sverchok

I am wondering if there has been any work done to create reciprocal frames in sverchok for generating/prototyping designs for architecture.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have not admitted any. But you can start https://gist.github.com/f25845210d1d3b7e542c65fb9c696409 from importing this one

Comment: whoa this is great! it would be cool to eventually generate parts with connections as detailed in this paper: https://pure.tue.nl/ws/portalfiles/portal/131842016/Godthelp_0946277.pdf